# REST junction/mix of resource retrieving. Which controller use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, sails.js

The problem is not easy to explain in english as I'm not.

Well this is simple I try to do a REST api and I could have these URI:

- get /events/10/users/2
- get /users/2/events/10

As you can see I can retrieve an user which is register inside an event and I can retrieve an event which is linked to a user. It's just an exemple.

My problem now is how to implement with good logic ? Which controller to use ? User or Event controller ?

Because of REST I have this mix of ressource and for sure something like /users?id=2&event=10 and /events?id=10&user=2 is more easy to understand and I know where to retrieve the user and the event.

Comment: Both controller to load the both ressource ? The problem is that in this way I could load a user and an event from the both controllers.

Comment: you think it is bad ? you will need anyway to connect user and events,  most probably events->users (just to check acl) so I could chose `get /events/10/users/2`  because user can not know about events but events probably have to know about users.

Comment: Thanks for your response, As you said I will use both because both are linked each other. To answer you I don't think it's bad but I'm just afraid of duplicate my code sometimes. After all maybe I can write some services to make some part common.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of these routes are really necessary or recommended for a clean REST API.  What you should have is:

```
get /events/10/users   <-- Get list of all users for event #10
get /users/2/events    <-- Get list of all events for user #2
get /events/10         <-- Get all info about event #10
get /users/2           <-- Get all info about user #2
```

There's no reason to access a user record via the events API, or vice versa--they should be accessed through their own APIs.

Comment: Yes it's more clean like this, it avoid the mixing problem. Thanks you.